# Is there a way to attack the SHA-3, GOST, and WHIRLPOOL hash functions?

Tags: hash, algorithm

Is there a way to attack SHA-3, GOST, and WHIRLPOOL hash functions?

Comment: Yes. My late great uncle in Nigeria recently expired, taking the secret to his grave. However, he has left it in a safety deposit box in the United States of America. If you are American citizen, I can make us rich together. Just send me $5000 by Western Union and I will send further instructions.

Answer (score 2):

As the [SHA-3 page on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-3) illustrates, there are currently no known attacks for the SHA-3 hash function that result in a cryptographic break.

The first cryptographic break for the [GOST hash function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GOST_%28hash_function%29) was published in 2008. See [cryptanalysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GOST_%28hash_function%29#Cryptanalysis) for more information.

The first cryptanalysis on a *reduced version* of the [WHIRLPOOL hash function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whirlpool_%28cryptography%29) (number of rounds *R* less than 10) was published in 2009. There is no known attack on the full WHIRLPOOL hash function (10 rounds).

Comment: It should also be noted that the cryptanalytic results on Whirlpool are on a _reduced_ version (less rounds than the nominal 10). There is no known attack on the full Whirlpool.

Comment: Thanks Thomas for pointing this out. I've edited my answer to include this additional information.